# Converge or diverge $\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{4^n(n!)^2}{(2n-1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show if the series converges or diverges.$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{4^n(n!)^2}{(2n-1)!}$$Can someone please help with proving this? (I think it converges)

Comment: Use the ratio test.

Comment: @pyrazolam with the ratio test the limit is 1

Comment: @pyrazolam Sadly this is one of those ghastly series where the ratio and root tests both give 1.

Comment: What does the $n$th term test say?

Comment: Since $\quad\displaystyle\frac{\big(2n\big)!}{\big(n!\big)^2}~=~{2n\choose n}\quad$ and $\quad\displaystyle\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\big(2x\big)^{2n}}{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}~n^2} ~=~ 2\arcsin^2x},\quad$ after repeatedly differentiating with regard to *x*, and multiplying by $2x$, we finally get $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\big(2x\big)^{2n}~\big(n!\big)^2}{\big(2n-1\big)!} ~=~ \dfrac x{\big(1-x^2\big)^2}~\bigg[\big(2x^2+1\big)~\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} - x~\big(4x^4-8x^2+1\big)\bigg],$$ which for $x=1$, as is the case here, clearly diverges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a_n=\dfrac{4^n(n!)^2}{(2n-1)!} = \dfrac{(2^n\cdot n!)^2}{(2n-1)!} = \dfrac{2\cdot 4\cdots (2n-2)\cdot (2n)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots (2n-2)\cdot (2n-1)}\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdots (2n) > \dfrac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n-2)\cdot (2n)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots (2n-2)\cdot (2n-1)}\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1) = \dfrac{(2n-1)!2n}{(2n-1)!}= 2n = b_n \to \text{ divergence}$ by comparison test with $\sum_{n} (2n)$

Comment: BRICS-Fan if $a_n=\dfrac{(-4)^n(n!)^2}{(2n-1)!}$?

Comment: @SeguraCubero Same problem in that case.

Comment: @Ian Ido not think that ... you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the divergence test you can see it diverges. The divergence test says if the limit of the function you're summing doesn't converge to 0, then the sum diverges. The the function you have is strictly increasing since 4^n*(n!)^2 increases way faster than (2n-1)!. Adding bigger and bigger terms means the sum diverges.

Comment: Your claim is false. Actually $\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n-1)!}$ decays faster than $a^n$ for any $a>1/4$. The $4^n$ in this problem is very important.

Comment: Completely true. My mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ratio test to evaluate:

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, if you get an answer less than 1 it converges, greater than 1 it is divergent and if it is 1, then this test fails.

Comment: Unfortunately, this limit is $1$ so the test fails :(